# Python Struct/Packing errors

Tags: python, sockets, struct, binary

I'm getting the following errors when using my code. My goal of this code is to create a class to convert integer inputs into binary data for socket messaging. I'm trying to understand packing and unpacking for this application. Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
import struct

def BinaryPacker(input1):
    s = struct.Struct('@I')
    pack_data = s.pack(int(input1))
    print 'Original values:', input1
    print 'Format string  :', s.format
    print 'Uses           :', s.size, 'bytes'
    return pack_data

#BinaryUnpacker unpacks the data with small discrepancy in floating point value
def BinaryUnpacker(input2):
    s = struct.Struct('@I')
    print input2
    print 'Size of struct: ', struct.calcsize(input2)
    unpack_data = s.unpack(input2)
    print 'Unpacked Values:', unpack_data
    print unpack_data[0]
    print '\n'

while True:
    print ("Message to pack n unpack:")
    message = raw_input() 
    message = BinaryPacker(message)
    BinaryUnpacker(message)
```

Error 1: For some reason using small numbers <10 appears to be interpreted as a char instead of a string although 9 appears to work.

```
Message to pack n unpack:
5
Original values: 5
Format string  : @I
Uses           : 4 bytes

Size of struct:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PythonPractice\BinaryPacker.py", line 43, in <module>
    BinaryUnpacker(message)
  File "C:\PythonPractice\BinaryPacker.py", line 33, in BinaryUnpacker
    print 'Size of struct: ', struct.calcsize(input2)
struct.error: bad char in struct format
```

Error 2: If I try to convert the input2 into an integer I get a literal error.

```
C:\PythonPractice>BinaryPacker.py
Message to pack n unpack:
9
Original values: 9
Format string  : @I
Uses           : 4 bytes

Size of struct:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PythonPractice\BinaryPacker.py", line 43, in <module>
    BinaryUnpacker(message)
  File "C:\PythonPractice\BinaryPacker.py", line 33, in BinaryUnpacker
    print 'Size of struct: ', struct.calcsize(int(input2))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

C:\PythonPractice>BinaryPacker.py
Message to pack n unpack:
10
Original values: 10
Format string  : @I
Uses           : 4 bytes


Size of struct:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PythonPractice\BinaryPacker.py", line 43, in <module>
    BinaryUnpacker(message)
  File "C:\PythonPractice\BinaryPacker.py", line 33, in BinaryUnpacker
    print 'Size of struct: ', struct.calcsize(int(input2))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Answer (score 0):

`struct.calcsize` takes a format string as argument, not an encoded byte object. In your case that would be `@I`.